# php mysql three left join method

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I have three table:

Article:

```
|id|title|timestamp|......
```

group_tags:

```
|id|content_id|tags_id
```

tags_name:

```
|id|name|
```

I need to list article title with any tag id:

```
function _tags_search_($id,$type){
    $DB_QUERY = mySqli::f("SELECT title FROM " . ARTICLES . " LEFT JOIN " . POSTS_TAGS . " ON " . ARTICLES . ".id = " . POSTS_TAGS . ".content_id WHERE 
    " .POSTS_TAGS . ".tags_id = ? AND approved = 1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 12", $id);

        foreach($DB_QUERY as $row){
         $data[] = $row;
        }

    return $data;
}
```

this worked for me and show list of article title.

But I need to show tag name for tags id in addition to list title like this:

```
Search result for : Linux
```

I have two way :

- three left join method ( **if true how do?**)
- fetch another query for show tag name.

I think `three join` is better and faster. how do show tags name with `three join` method?!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT title, name from
group_tags g
INNER JOIN article ON a.id = g.content_id
INNER JOIN tags_name t ON t.id = g.tags_id
```

Let me know if you face any issue